# C++ lost reference

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
class Event{
    string name;
    string description;
    vector<Employee> assignedEmployees;
    Date date;
    Level requiredLevel;
public:
    bool addEmployee(Employee &employee);   //adds employee to the vector 'assignedEmployees'
    vector<Employee> getAssignedEmployees() const {return this->assignedEmployees;};
    //...

class Calendar {
    int year;
    bool leap;
    set <Event> events;
public:
    bool addEvent(Event &event);
    Event getNearestEvent() const;  //from set 'events' returns first value
    //...

bool Calendar::addEvent(Event &event) {
    //some conditions

    this->events.insert(event);
    return true;
}

bool Event::addEmployee(Employee &employee){
    if (isAssigned(employee) == true) {
        return false;
    }
    //some conditions
    assignedEmployees.push_back(employee);
    return true;
}
```

I'm creating tests to check, whether it works or not as intended. This is one of my tests:

```
TEST(MyTest, TestDescription) {
    Calendar cal1(2017);
    Calendar cal2(2018);
    Employee emp1("A"); Employee emp2("B");
    Date date1; date1 << "14.2.2017";   //not important part for this problem
    Date date2; date2 << "29.2.2018";
    Event projectLaunch(date1, "projectLaunchName", "projectLaunchDescription");
    //PLACE B
    cal1.addEvent(projectLaunch)
    //PLACE A
    ASSERT_EQ(2, cal1.getNearestEvent().getAssignedEmployees().size());
}
```

So I expect this assert to be true (because I really assign 2 employees to Event 'projectLaunch' by the following code). But it's result depends on where I put it:

```
projectLaunch.addEmployee(emp1);
projectLaunch.addEmployee(emp2);
```

I have 2 options - as I marked above - place A or B. I would like to prefer place A, but here it returns 0 (so ASSERT_EQ(2,0) is not true). When I put it on B, it is true. Where is the problem? Am I losing references when adding an event to calendar class and then asking from calendar instance?

Answer (score 1):

When you add an event to your calendar, the event is copied.  When you make changes to `projectLaunch` after the add, these changes are made to the local variable and not the copy stored in `cal1`.

In addition, the value stored in a `set` is `const`, as making any changes to it can invalidate the sort order the set depends on.  So changing the value after adding it to the set is not feasible.  (Note that it is possible to change values stored in a set, but this needs to be done very carefully.  Typically and object would be extracted from the set, changed, and reinserted.)

You'll have to keep adding employees to the event before you add it the calendar.